# QComboBox of QCheckBoxes, cant see QCheckBox, just the text

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, combobox

I wrote a simple code to make a combobox of checkable checkboxes. But I cant see actual checkbox that I could check or uncheck, I see just the text:

[image]

[image]

Heres my code:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QComboBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

private slots:

    void buttonclicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->model = new QStandardItemModel(4, 1); // 4 rows, 1 col
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
    {
        QStandardItem* item;
        if(r == 0)
            item = new QStandardItem(QString("All"));
        else
            item = new QStandardItem(QString("Item %0").arg(r));

        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);

        model->setItem(r, 0, item);
    }

    ui->comboBox->setModel(model);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonclicked()));
}

void MainWindow::buttonclicked()
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0; i<ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
    {
        QModelIndex index = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
        QVariant v = index.data(Qt::CheckStateRole);
        int j = v.toInt();
        if(j == 2)
        {
            QModelIndex ii = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
            QString text = ii.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            qDebug() << text;
        }

    }
    qDebug()<<"";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Qt 4.8 and 5.1.

Comment: Try with a different QStyle to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank Osterfeld mentioned try different QStyle. I am facing similar issue. The `QCheckBox` inside `QComboBox` does not work when I use `Fusion` Style. This has been raised as [QTBUG-60310](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60310)